# How do I run my spark job automatically and periodically (eg every 24 hours)?

Tags: deployment, apache-spark, jobs

I have no practice of Spark. With simple examples, I learned: 
Run application locally,
Run on a Spark standalone cluster in client deploy mode.

I need to shoot a spark job automatically and periodically (eg every 24 hours). Does anyone know help me out on how to proceed? We're forced to use YARN?
Thank you for the time dedicated to me.

Comment: You can schedule it through Oozie. https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/DG_SparkActionExtension.html

Comment: Thank you. So it is not necessary to use YARN? And I can use Spark with Oozie without Hadoop? Thanks again.

Comment: Ooize lets you to submit jobs in YARN.